# Redirect using .htaccess from a PHP page to another both with variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a simple question, but I cant find the way to do it. I need to redirect or rewrite this:

```
http://mydomain.com/libro.php?isbn=9788493652470
```

To this:

```
http://mydomain.com/busqueda.php?busqueda=medimecum
```

I have already tried this but it doesn’t work:

```
Redirect 301 /libro.php?isbn=9788493652470 http://mydomain.com/busqueda.php?busqueda=medimecum
```

Comment: Those two files share the whole head part, and I tried also the PHP solution "header()", but it goes on a loop... I cant make it work, even using the "if ($_GET=9788493652470)"

Comment: You can't match query string in `Redirect` directive use `mod_rewrite` rules instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight `Redirect` would not work well. But using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with a `RewriteCond` for a query string would work well. This should work for your example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} isbn=9788493652470
RewriteRule ^libro.php http://mydomain.com/busqueda.php?busqueda=medimecum [L,R=301]
```

Now looking at your question again it’s not clear if you want to pass along the original query string, correct?  So this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/libro.php?isbn=9788493652470
```

Would become this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/busqueda.php?busqueda=medimecum&isbn=9788493652470
```

But if somehow you wanted to do that, you could add the [`QSA`](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) (Query String Append) flag to that `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} isbn=9788493652470
RewriteRule ^libro\.php http://mydomain.com/busqueda.php?busqueda=medimecum [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: +1 it should work just change regex to `^libro\.php$`

Comment: `^libro.php` may work but it will also match `libro-php123` etc.